# Spring-Integration: shouldCopyRequestHeaders

Tags: spring-integration

We just updated Spring-Integration from 3.* to 4.1.6 and it seems that there is a new feature on the MessageHandlers, which is triggered by the flag shouldCopyRequestHeaders, that seems to merge all headers of a splitter or recipientList component. It defaults to true. Can we set that flag to false without writing our own component? It causes us a lot of distress, like mixing up Content-Type and Accept headers in outbound-gateway's in a complete inappropiate way

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new feature, it's been there since 2.0.0 to **not** copy headers for transformers and filters (but defaults to true for other endpoints). Before that, headers were unconditionally copied for **all** endpoints. See [this commit from 2010](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/b42d5b84ad550a274c803e192329c196a4bd7b1a#diff-c234700fe4a387491f2931390e2307e1).

Can you provide an example where you see a behavior change between 3.0 and 4.1.6 ?